# send data from vuejs to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

i have a laravel page which contains a reserve form i redirect my user after selecting date now for number of people and counting the price i use vuejs but i want to pass the data to the laravel form and submit that from laravel with all the other data so here is a part of my code :

```
  your final price

 <input type="number" style=" background-color:#fff; border:none" v-model="finalPrice" disabled/>
```

and here is js part i cuted out code for better reading :

```
 <script>
  this.epic_price = this.sum_price + (this.total_price * this.sum_day)
  this.$emit('input', this.epic_price)
  </script>
```

although this form is not complete yet but i want to use it here in this page so i just paste it consider the form is not complete at all :

```
 <form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right m-form--group-seperator-dashed"
              action="/properties/savereserve/" method="post">
        <div class="row">
                @foreach($price as $key => $prices)
                    <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                        {{$date[$key]}}
                        <hr>
                        {{$prices}}
                    </div>
                @endforeach
        </div>
        </form>
```

//exacly on the same page i use my vue component so they are on the same page

```
                <reserve
                :sum_price="{{$sumprice}}"
                :sum_day="{{$sumday}}"
                :base_price="{{$property->base_price}}"
                :property_id="{{$property->id}}"
                :user_id="{{Auth::user()->id}}"
            ></reserve>
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but in order to send data from Vuejs to Laravel you would need to use an XMLHttpRequest to send the data. Through Vue this is commonly done through Axios where you would GET or POST to a given URL that your Laravel backend is set to handle data incoming from.

Comment: @kalenpw thanks for the answer let me make it simple i want to do some calculation on data and use that data on the same page but on the laravel section not the vuejs thats all should i send it now ??